# Error during non-english keyboard typing on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing an app for iPad and when I type in searchbar using keyboard with russian layout it constantly writes errors in log (but works fine). Searchbar is standart.

Error looks like this (letter combination after "/tmp." changes according to pressed key:

```
Mapping '/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards/images/tmp.B943Tm5q' failed: 'Invalid argument' (22)
```

App works fine, though, but those errors are irritating, I don't need so much garbage in logs.

What are those errors and how do I fix them? I tried googling. A lot. But answers don't even come close to what I'm searching.

UPD: errors are shown not only when typing, but at any keyboard state change: when it appears, when I switch language, when I press any button (even shift).

Answer (score 3):

It's an OS issue. You should report it at http://bugreporter.apple.com . There's nothing you can do about it in your app though, so don't waste time worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its because your mixing iOS versions/releases. I believe.